# How to create copies of the same object (e.g Label)?

Tags: java, javafx

I want to add copies of a `Label` to a `Pane`.

```
Timeline timer = new Timeline(
        new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000),
                new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {
                    @Override
                    public void handle(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
                        Label egg_new = new Label();
                        egg_new = egg;
                        getChildren().add(egg_new);
                    }
                }));
timer.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
timer.play();
```

It gives me an error because I can't add the same object to a `Pane`. How can I make a copy of `egg`? My label basically contains an egg icon, assume that my goal is to create a new copy of egg icon and add it to the `Pane` every second.

I tried copying the image of `egg` and setting it to `egg_new` but the `egg` dissapears then. This is how I do it:

```
Label egg_new = new Label();
ImageView egg_new_img = egg_img;
egg_new.setGraphic(egg_new_img);
getChildren().add(egg_new);
```

Comment: @Abra As I mentioned in my question, my label contains an image, not a text. I can copy the image, but still, isn't there a way to copy the `Label` object?

Comment: There's no built-in method to do that. Why not simply create a method that creates the labels you need with appropriate input data, and then call the method repeatedly if you need the "same" label?

Comment: Have you confirmed that the label object does not implement .clone()?

Comment: @James_D I understand what you mean, but how can I copy the images? When I set the `ImageView` of one label to another the image of first one dissapears. I get the image as a local file.

Comment: Your method would create a new `ImageView` (using the same `Image`) each time it's called. (I'm not sure you did understand what I meant, because there would be no "copying images" in that scenario)

Comment: @James_D Did you mean writing a custom copy constructor?

Comment: @olimpiabaku No, not at all. That's completely unviable as there are so many properties, styles, CSS pseudoclasses, etc. that you could potentially need to copy.

Comment: I think what you're missing here is the idea that you have to copy one label. Don't; just create the labels exactly the same way each time you need one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a method to create the `Label`, and call it when you need one. That way you ensure the label is created the same way each time.

Note that no `Node` subclass instance can appear multiple times in the scene graph, so if you want the "same" `Label` you need to create a new `Label` each time, and create it in the same way. Similarly, if the `Label` has a `graphic` set, you need to create a new `Node` (e.g. `ImageView`) for the `graphic` each time.

```
private Image eggImage = ... ;

private Label createEggLabel() {
    Label eggLabel = new Label();
    ImageView eggImg = new ImageView(eggImage);
    eggLabel.setGraphic(eggImg);
    return eggLabel ;
}
```

and then

```
Timeline timer = new Timeline(
    new KeyFrame(Duration.millis(1000),
        event -> getChildren().add(createEggLabel())));
timer.setCycleCount(Timeline.INDEFINITE);
timer.play();
```